# SQL FOR JSON - Add additional array bracket

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

i´m pretty long searching for an answer to the following question. 
How can i add an additional array bracket in the subselect?

I have the following Query:

```
select 
    -- Images
    (
        SELECT  tMedien.WebshopID   AS 'mediaId',
                (   SELECT  Farbe   AS 'name'
                    FROM    tMedien tOptions
                    WHERE   tOptions.ID = tMedien.ID
                    FOR JSON PATH
                )                   AS 'options'
        FROM    tMedien
        WHERE   tMedien.Hauptartikelnummer  = tHauptartikel.Hauptartikelnummer
        ORDER BY Position
        FOR JSON auto
    )                                                           AS 'images'
FROM        v2Artikelstamm tHauptartikel    
WHERE       Artikelnummer = 'XXXX'
FOR JSON PATH
```

With the output:

```
[{"images":[{"mediaId":187,"options":[{"name":"904"}]},{"mediaId":188,"options":[{"name":"910"}]},{"mediaId":189,"options":[{"name":"971"}]},{"mediaId":190,"options":[{"name":"982"}]},{"mediaId":191,"options":[{"name":"A94"}]},{"mediaId":192,"options":[{"name":"A95"}]}]}]
```

But for the shopware rest api i need following to successfully assign pictures: ( "options":[[ )

```
[{"images":[{"mediaId":187,"options":[[{"name":"904"}]]},{"mediaId":188,"options":[[{"name":"910"}]]},{"mediaId":189,"options":[[{"name":"971"}]]},{"mediaId":190,"options":[[{"name":"982"}]]},{"mediaId":191,"options":[[{"name":"A94"}]]},{"mediaId":192,"options":[[{"name":"A95"}]]}]}]
```

How can i query that?

Thank you.

BR Dominik

Comment: Untested, but `JSON_QUERY('[' + (SELECT ... FOR JSON) + ']')` should do. This is a bit ugly, but I don't think there's a "clean" way for wrapping it in another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for comment, i tried it and it solves my problem. :)

Here is the required query:

```
SELECT
    -- Images
    (
        SELECT  tMedien.WebshopID   AS 'mediaId',
                JSON_QUERY('[' + 
                (   SELECT  Farbe   AS 'name'
                    FROM    tMedien tOptions
                    WHERE   tOptions.ID = tMedien.ID
                    FOR JSON PATH
                ) + ']')            AS 'options'
        FROM    tMedien
        WHERE   tMedien.Hauptartikelnummer  = tHauptartikel.Hauptartikelnummer
        ORDER BY Position
        FOR JSON auto
    )                                                           AS 'images'

FROM        v2Artikelstamm tHauptartikel    
WHERE       Artikelnummer = 'BR2000060'
FOR JSON PATH
```